# What is the best approach for setting up a good, secure smtp server on Debian?

Tags: debian, smtp, authentication, spf, dkim

Which server do you recommend? (postfix?)
Which configuration for authenticating users for sending mail?
Which setups for making it inbox friendly (dkim, spf, domainkey etc)?

Is there some detailed guide to walk a newbie through all or most of these?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up an SMTP server is not for the faint of heart - especially so if you are a newbie.

If this is for real production use, I would recommend out-sourcing your SMTP needs to some online service. However, if it is for personal/hobby use, you can look up a tonne of online tutorials on how to do things.

In my experience, the easiest mail server to setup on Debian is Citadel. Straightforward apt-get, provides a web-based interface and command-line interface for configuration and mail access. Supports all kinds of features.

Good luck.